Instancing faces as objects
I am trying to make a procedural cave system. I have created 5 different walls and I want to instance them on the faces of the white object named as "Cave" (Check outliner).
I have applied rotations and scales of walls.
I made sure all the walls z-axis look the same direction which is world space z-axis.

I have tried a simple GeoNode (got instructions from reddit and chatgpt, I am not much familiar with GeoNodes). 2nd picture is the result of the GeoNodes.

If I could describe what I am trying to do properly, could you help me?

Yes, you have instanced your objects on the faces. What exactly is your problem?

"If I could describe what I am trying to do properly, could you help me?" - it depends how you ask your question. You can read this post that explains how to ask a good question on BSE.

A naive solution: click "reset children" in the collection info, and plug a "normal" node to the "vector" input of align rotation to vector

This is the answer to the question being asked.  However, if I were trying to guess what OP is trying to do, it is stack all the rocks in the form of whatever tunnel he creates.

Your objects are not rotating correctly for a couple reasons.
Applying scales/transforms is a good step.  To make sure your objects' origins are correct, you can select them and use (f3 to search) Origin to Geometry.
Separate and Reset Children can both be checked if you don't want the instanced objects to move when you move the corresponding collection info objects.
Adding a Normal Node to the align rotation can help to rotate instances correctly.
In the image below all instances are basically walls of the default cube with noise textures:

If this solution still doesn't work for you, and you are more interested in stacking all these irregularly shaped rocks, you can try this node tree.
The process is described in a video called Turning ANYTHING into Rocks - Blender Geometry Nodes.  Here is the procedure:
a)first break the imported object into a series of a more or less hexagonal grid cells but randomize the generation(, Triangulate, Dual Mesh)
b)splits their edges somewhat Randomly,(Random Value, Split Edges)
c)give them subdivisions to round them,(Subdivision Surface)
d)add noise to them and extrude them. (Noise Texture, Extrude)
The result is quite different and does not even use instances, but creates procedurally generated geometry per face, the advantage being, we can create a bunch of stacked stones that are all irregular shapes.

To add more randomness to the shapes:


